# How to change a cell's code after it's been moved in Excel using VBA

Tags: date, excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA Script I've written with help, I am not a neophyte when it comes to coding, but to me so far Excel VBA has been an arsenic nightmare wrapped in a sugar pill sold by MS as a language easy to learn.

Ok, rant out of the way sorry, but I digress.

Here is the complete script:

```
Option Explicit

Sub tgr()

    Dim wsB As Worksheet 'BackOrder
    Dim wsJ As Worksheet 'Jobs List
    Dim wsA As Worksheet 'Archive
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set wsB = Sheets("BackOrder")
    Set wsJ = Sheets("Jobs List")
    Set wsA = Sheets("Archive")

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    With Intersect(wsJ.UsedRange, wsJ.Columns("N"))
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>Same"
        With Intersect(.Offset(2).EntireRow, .Parent.Range("B:L"))
            .Copy wsA.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    LastRow = wsB.Range("B6").End(xlDown).Row
    wsB.Range("P5:Q5").Copy wsB.Range("P6:Q" & LastRow)
    Calculate
    wsB.UsedRange.Copy Sheets.Add.Range("A1")

    With Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Columns("Q"))
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>Different"
        .EntireRow.Delete
        With .Parent
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("G")).Cut .Range("F1")
            Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("H")).Cut .Range("G1")
            Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("L")).Cut .Range("H1")
            Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("N")).Cut .Range("I1")
            Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("B:J")).Copy wsJ.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .Delete
        End With
    End With

    LastRow = wsJ.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    wsJ.Range("M1:T1").Copy
    wsJ.Range("B3:I" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    wsJ.Range("U1:W1").Copy wsJ.Range("J3:L" & LastRow)
    wsJ.Range("X1:Y1").Copy wsJ.Range("M3:N" & LastRow)

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

As you can see this is a three page script, BackOrder, Jobs List, and Archive, what I need to do is in Archive. The cells in Columns in J & K use TODAY() as a way to tell the rest of the script when it looks in the cell in column F how many days early or late it is.

Column J shows early, Column K shows late.

Column J's script is:

```
=IF(F3-TODAY()<0,"",F3-TODAY())
```

Column K's script is:

```
=IF(TODAY()-F3<1,"",TODAY()-F3)
```

Column F in this case is part of the larger script, which moves data via an import and has no formatting.

Now, when I bring row into Archive, I want it to be where the cells, instead of having TODAY() in either script, I want it to show the date it was moved over there, so it will still be today, but instead of TODAY(), it will have the date in this format ##/##/##. It will "freeze" the count of J & K so it will be accurate from that day forward, so we will know if it was shipped late, early, or on time.

Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: Have I read your question correctly?  Are you placing formulae in columns J and K that are then re-calculated every day?  Why not: `.Cells(Row, "J").Value = Now()`? This will fix the cell to the date/time the code was run.

Comment: But wouldn't that change when you open the sheet again? So wouldn't it happen where NOW() run two weeks ago become today if the sheet is open again?

Comment: `Now()` is a function that returns the date and time it was executed by a macro which my statement stores as a value. A minute ago `Now()` returned 41003.673287037. 41003 = days since 1Jan1900 = 4 Apr 12. .673287037 is about 16:08/24:00.

Comment: So Now() only runs once? Not each time the document opens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing worksheet functions and VBA functions.  You stopped your rant too soon although I think Word VBA is the worst version.

With the user interface, I can go to cell A1 and type "4apr12".  Excel recognises this as a date, stores the value as 41003 and sets the format to "dd-mmm-yy" which is the standard format closest to what I typed.

Alternately, I could type "41003" then go to the format menu and select or enter a date format of my choice.

Yet another choice is to type "=TODAY()".  Excel stores the value as "=TODAY()" but because of the leading equals, it evaluates this as an expression when it is entered and displays the value as a standard date (format dd/mm/yy here in the UK) and re-evaluates the expression when the workbook is opened and saved and when told to do so via the Calculate options.

VBA functions are different.  Even when they do the same thing, they often have different names.  The nearest equivalent to TODAY() is Now().  This function returns the current date and time as a number.  The integer part is the days since 1-Jan-1900; the fraction part is (Number of seconds since midnight)/(Number of seconds in a day).  So at midday today, Now() would have returned "41003.5".  This is a number; I can multiple it by two, subtract 5000 or whatever.

With VBA, I could execute:

```
Range("A1").Value = "4apr12"
```

Excel recognises this as a date just as if I had typed it from the user interface.

Alternatively, I could execute:

```
Range("A1").Value = 41003.5
```

This is just a number and will be stored and displayed as 41003.5.

If I want it to be displayed as a date, I must execute:

```
With Range("A1")
  .Value = 41003.5
  .NumberFormat = "dd mmm yy"
End With
```

The value is still saved as 41003.5 but I have told Excel to display it as 4 Apr 12.

I can execute:

```
Range("A1").Value = "=TODAY()"
```

This is treated just as if I had typed this formula from the interface.

But suppose I execute:

```
With Range("A1")
  .Value = Now()
  .NumberFormat = "dd mmm yy"
End With
```

Now() returns the current date and time as a number.  Excel stores it as a number but displays it as a date because I have told it to.  It will never re-evaluate because it is a simple numeric value not an expression involving functions.

I hope you this makes sense and helps you get your mind around the differences between Worksheet functions and VBA functions.  Excel and VBA are like learning to drive a car.  The first time you KNOW you will NEVER be able to do all these different things at the same time.  Yet, a month or two later, you are playing with the pedals, the gear stick, wheel and indicator while checking the mirror.  I do not understand why people think patting your head and rubbing your stomach is such as big deal.  All I can say is that sudenly the mist will clear and Excel and VBA will make sense.

Comment: A MS product and VBA should not be in the same sentence in my personal opinion, thanks for the head up with Word, honestly though I never thought about trying VBA in word... that thought scares me alone. 

That being said, the last bit of code sounds like it should work perfectly, except I do have a question, it's not explicit is it?

In any case, thanks for the help, I thought about something like that, but honestly I was too afraid to move things because right now VBA is a fickle mistress that I want to throw into the arctic and imagine I never saw in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand "it's not explicit is it?"  BTW, I think your code uses some very difficult methods.

Comment: Just like my code, it defines it's function.  And I use difficult methods because of the documents I am working with to make functional. Look up Fishbowl and its exporting ability and you'll see what I'm working with.